# strtok and (null) in C

Tags: c, parsing, strtok

I am trying to use strtok to separate a string by a comma. The line looks like this:

```
A:K149, A:N171, A:T172
```

I am using the following code.

```
 pch=strtok(line,",");
 printf("%s\n",pch);

        while(pch!=NULL){
        pch=strtok(NULL,", ");        
            printf("%s\n",pch);
        }
```

But what gets printed is:

```
A:K149
A:N171
A:T172

(null)
```

How do I get rid of the extra line and the (null) at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the order of your statements in while loop like this:-

```
while(pch!=NULL){
printf("%s\n",pch);
pch=strtok(NULL,", ");        
}
```

You should first print the value and then fetch the next sequence of characters(string) using `strtok`. It will ensure that `pch` is checked for `NULL` before its content are printed.

Comment: I would suggest you to use **","** as delimiter and trim strtok answer,  so when delimiting text only by **","** and not **", "** it will work also.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are printing the line before you test if it is null.

Basically, in your loop you test if it is null, then you update the value (which now could be null) and then you print it. So at the end it prints null, tests and sees the null and then quits the while loop.

Try this

```
pch=strtok(line,",");

while(pch!=NULL){
    printf("%s\n",pch);
    pch=strtok(NULL,", ");        
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while(pch!=NULL){
 printf("%s\n",pch);
        pch=strtok(NULL,", ");        

        }
```